# How to return an empty result from callback and continue scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

If return `None` or an empty list from a Request callback - scraping will be terminated. What if I want just ignore this request and continue process scheduled requests?

Comment: do you have some example code?

Comment: @shavenwarthog I've mistakened - scraping was terminating because spider tried to crawl url from domain that is not in `allowed_domains` attribute.

Comment: @GillBates - Have you considered using Drop Item http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#dropitem ?

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 options:

## if you did not use yield

```
return
#or
return None
```

## if you did use yield

```
#to interrupt parse function  execution
return

#to return None for current item and continue parse function execution
yield None
# or just do nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a scrapy exception [`DropItem`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#dropitem) while processing an item in Item Pipeline.

Check the [**example**](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#item-pipeline-example) specified in Scrapy docs.

e,g. Sample code example from the docs.

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class PricePipeline(object):
    vat_factor = 1.15

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['price']:
            if item['price_excludes_vat']:
               item['price'] = item['price'] * self.vat_factor
               return item
            else:
               raise DropItem("Missing price in %s" % item)
```